# lighthouse php use eloquent model accessors and mutators

Tags: php, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-php

I'm using lighthouse for graphql on top of my laravel application. I know how to define types. But how can I use the model accessor in the type definition of schema? For example, i have type use like this

```
type User {
   id: ID!
   name: String
}
```

But I don't have a `name` column in the database table but I have a name accessor in my eloquent model which I want to use in this case instead of weird column name. Is there any way I can use the model accessor?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean methods like `getFirstNameAttribute`? Simply define a field in snake case in your scheme, for my example it would be `first_name: String`

```
type User {
   #...
   first_name: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine if you are using laravel accessor `get{Attribute}Attribute`, you can also use `@method` directive:

```
type User {
   #...
   name: String @method(name: "getName")
}
```

Checkout:
https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#method
&
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor